# Implementing IERC721Enumerable interface

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to understand implementing an interface with a contract.

In my case, I'm using `IERC721Enumerable` so I can easily find which minted NFT's are owned by the user and then showcase it on the frontend when the user connects their wallet.

I understand with an interface, it's up to me to implement the 3 functions that come with `IERC721Enumerable`.

So my question is, how would I write the following functions?

```
  function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256) {

  }

  function tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address owner, uint256 index) external view returns (uint256 tokenId) {

  }

  function tokenByIndex(uint256 index) external view returns (uint256) {
    
  }
```

Here is the full contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

import {Base64} from "./libraries/Base64.sol";

contract MakeNFT is ERC721URIStorage, IERC721Enumerable {
  using Counters for Counters.Counter;
  Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

   // This is our SVG code. All we need to change is the word that's displayed. Everything else stays the same.
  // So, we make a baseSvg variable here that all our NFTs can use.
  string baseSvg = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' preserveAspectRatio='xMinYMin meet' viewBox='0 0 350 350'><style>.base { fill: white; font-family: serif; font-size: 24px; }</style><rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='black' /><text x='50%' y='50%' class='base' dominant-baseline='middle' text-anchor='middle'>";

  string[] firstWords = ["Dark", "Light", "Platninum", "Stone", "Wood", "Mirrored", "Water", "Thunder", "Giant", "Glitched"];
  string[] secondWords = ["Elf", "Cyborg", "Orc", "Human", "AI", "Dwarf", "Human", "Shapeshifter", "Gargoyle", "Wolf", "Hybrid Human"];
  event NewNFTMinted(address sender, uint256 tokenId);

  constructor() ERC721 ("web3-blitz", "BLITZ") {
    console.log("Generated NFT.");
  }

  function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256) {

  }

  function tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address owner, uint256 index) external view returns (uint256 tokenId) {

  }

  function tokenByIndex(uint256 index) external view returns (uint256) {
    
  }

  function pickRandomFirstWord(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
    // I seed the random generator. More on this in the lesson. 
    uint256 rand = random(string(abi.encodePacked("FIRST_WORD", Strings.toString(tokenId))));
    // Squash the # between 0 and the length of the array to avoid going out of bounds.
    rand = rand % firstWords.length;
    return firstWords[rand];
  }

  function pickRandomSecondWord(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) {
    uint256 rand = random(string(abi.encodePacked("SECOND_WORD", Strings.toString(tokenId))));
    rand = rand % secondWords.length;
    return secondWords[rand];
  }


  function random(string memory input) internal pure returns(uint256) {
    return uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(input)));
  }

  function generateNFT() public {
    uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();

    string memory first = pickRandomFirstWord(newItemId);
    string memory second = pickRandomSecondWord(newItemId);
    string memory combinedWord = string(abi.encodePacked(first, second));

    string memory finalSvg = string(abi.encodePacked(baseSvg, combinedWord, "</text></svg>"));
    
   string memory json = Base64.encode(
        bytes(
            string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    '{"name": "',
                    // We set the title of our NFT as the generated word.
                    combinedWord,
                    '", "description": "A highly acclaimed collection of squares.", "image": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,',
                    // We add data:image/svg+xml;base64 and then append our base64 encode our svg.
                    Base64.encode(bytes(finalSvg)),
                    '"}'
                )
            )
        )
    );
    string memory finalTokenUri = string(
        abi.encodePacked("data:application/json;base64,", json)
    );
    
    console.log("\n--------------------");
    console.log(finalTokenUri);
    console.log("--------------------\n");

    _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, finalTokenUri);
    _tokenIds.increment();
    console.log("An NFT w/ ID %s has been minted to %s", newItemId, msg.sender);
    emit NewNFTMinted(msg.sender, newItemId);


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you imported the library you don'y have to rewritte the function unless you want to override them.

For instance

```
MyContract is ERC20Upgradeable {


uint bal = balanceOf(msg.sender);

// You have direct access to it.because it's in the import and your contract Is import.

}
```

Because you are importing the library and declaring the contract as **IS** ERC20Upgradeable. Your contract will already interface all of the function of the ERC20Upgradeable. This is why balanceOf is accessible even if we did not write it the function.

This mean that function like totalSupply() are present even if you don't write the function yourself.

In your case your probably look for something like this in the front end

```
let balance = await nftContract.methods.balanceOf(account).call()

for (let i = 0; i < balance; i++) {
      let nft = await IDXNFT.methods.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(account, i).call()
```

)

What is going on here?

```
tokenOfOwnerByIndex(account, i)
```

This function will return the nft id based on the index and is to be used with the balance.

if you have a balance of 5 NFT.
The `index[0]` is your first NFT.
The `index[1]` is your second NFT.

`i` is the `index` in the loop.

So this loop will return each NFT owned by the account.

Now in your contract You should start with this.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";



contract MakeNFT is   ERC721Enumerable {


  constructor() ERC721("web3-blitz", "BLITZ")  {
    
  }
```

This will give you the base to start with. You might need to override some functions if you want to change the behaviour of the original one.

Comment: Got it. But without redeclaring the function, I get the following error: `Contract "MakeNFT" should be marked as abstract.`. But then when I try to make the contract abstract, it won't let me deploy.

Comment: Might be your constructor that need to be public

Comment: Thanks for your patience. When I try adding public to the constructor, the following error is shown: `Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient.`

Comment: Look at the edit i have made. start with this base for your contract. add each component one by one.